# Calculation of charge defect formation energy

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, defects

I am confused about the calculation of the charge defect formation energy equation with these two terms (from figure below):

1. $\Delta V$: alignment term, and
2. $E_{corr}$: correlation term.

How can I calculate these two terms by using VASP package?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**First**, the energy correction term, $E_{corr}$.
It arises due to presence of periodic boundary conditions (defects are spuriously repeated) and of background charge compensation (hidden from the user). There are several correction schemes, but all of them requires the knowledge of the dielectric constant of the system:

- Generally used "FNV" scheme https://doi.org/10.1103/physrevlett.102.016402, https://doi.org/10.1103/physrevb.89.195205;
- Easier to use Lany and Zunger scheme https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.78.235104 (requires Madelung constant $\alpha_M$ of the crystal).

**Second**, potential alignment term (PA, $\Delta V$). Never seen such, looks like a compensation of imperfectness of DFT band energies (in particular, VBM).

UPD: formula from Lany and Zunger suitable for calculation

$E_{corr} \approx \frac{2}{3} \frac{\alpha_M q^2} {\varepsilon L}$,

where $L$ is the size of the cell (in Angstrom), $q$ - charge (in e), $\varepsilon$ - dielectric constant. Resulted energy is in eV.

Comment: +1 but if I understood correctly, the OP asked about some implementations (how to calculate the defect formation energy, not the theoretical description of the calculation method). In that case, [PyCDT](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2018.01.004) and [doped](https://doped.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorials.html) are just two of the codes that automate this process of finding each term of the defect formation energy and works with VASP. There are others code too such as [Spinney.](https://spinney.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html)

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin if you could provide your comment as an answer along with the theoretical background raised by Leon, then that would be great, thank you!

Comment: thanks for the point, @AbdulMuhaymin. Added equation for calculations which we used in [our study](https://www.mdpi.com/2079-4991/11/11/2978) (differs in length units from Lany and Zunger). I have not used the mentioned software, agree that  answer mentioned them would be nice!